# NodeJs, Express, BodyParse and JSON

Tags: json, node.js, express, body-parser

I'm trying to implement a simple server using Express 4.0 and parsing messages with BodyParser. To test my server I use Postman.

Using `x-www-form-urlencoded` as message mode it works with no problem but changing messages with `JSON` I can't parte data using `BodyParse`.

Here is my code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

var router = express.Router()

router.get('/', function (req, res){

    res.json({message: "nd..."})
})

var sendRoute = router.route('/msg')
sendRoute.post(function(req, res){ 

    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM******************************
// It works with urlencoded request but not with JSON 
    var dataparam1 =    req.body.param1
    var dataparam2 =    req.body.param2
    ****************************************************
    .
    .
    .
})
```

and let's say this is the JSON data I get form the request:

```
[{"param1":"This is the param1", 
  "param2":"This is the param2"
}]
```

What's wrong with my code? how can I get params sent with JSON format?

Comment: What does `console.log(req.headers['content-type'])` show inside your POST route when you send a JSON request?

Comment: Uhm... `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`

Comment: In postman I've set raw and JSON.

Comment: That's also not valid JSON that you've showed in your question. Keys have to be enclosed in double quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your request body is sent as a JSON string, then you must tell your app that via a content-type header.

1. In Postman, click the `Headers` button, next to the drop-down to select the method and the `URL params` button. (Top right)
2. A table will expand, fill in `Content-Type` in the left field and `application/json` in the right field.
3. Submit the request.

`bodyParser` can handle multiple types of data, but it must know what format you're submitting. It will not attempt to guess the data type.

The drop-down menu (according to your comment, it's set to 'JSON' at the moment) just above the textarea where you fill in the request body only toggles syntax highlighting, it does not set the Content-Type header for you.

Comment: If the incoming object can't be parsed, then your JSON is invalid. You're probably not quoting keys (`{"key":"val"}` vs `{key:"val"}`). They're *not* optional in JSON. *Edit: I see you've removed your comment so I suppose it worked? :-)*